# How to find the number of participants of a past event?

Tags: api

How to find the number of participants happened in the past?

Comment: Welcome to SE.  This is tagged as 'api' - are you looking to find the number of participants using the API, or through the normal UI?

Answer (score 2):

I usually just go to

Events >> Find Participants

Then I do a search for the event and it will give you the list and a count.